# Python - Dynamic programing doesn't improve speed

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I wanted to creating N-Dimensional board for Minesweepers/Cheess, and I ran into a problem when I've used DP to improve the speed but, the speed appearingly the same between two version.

**Version 1: Naive recursion**

```
def createboard_nd(dimensions, value=None):
       if len(dimensions) == 1:
           return [value for _ in range(dimensions[0])]
       else:
           return [createboard_nd(dimensions[1:], value) for _ in range(dimensions[0])]
```

**Version 2: Recursion with DP**

```
def createboard_nd(dimensions, value=None, memo=None):
       if memo is None:
           memo = {}
       if len(dimensions) in memo:
           return memo[len(dimensions)]
       if len(dimensions) == 1:
           memo[len(dimensions)] = [value for _ in range(dimensions[0])]
           return memo[len(dimensions)]
       else:
           memo[len(dimensions)] = [createboard_nd(dimensions[1:],value, memo) for _ in range(dimensions[0])]
           return memo[len(dimensions)]
```

**Example**

```
createboard_nd((10,10,10,10,10,10), 1)
```

Comment: I have updated the using example. It took about around the same

Comment: Odd. In my testing, the latter is about 3000 times faster. What times did you measure for each?

Comment: (Not that it really matters, since both are doing fundamentally different things and the latter is most certainly not doing what you want.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about the latter code?

Comment: I can also confirm the `Version 2: Recursion with DP` is thousands of times faster.

Comment: Well you're intentionally reusing the same list objects. How do you intend to handle that later when you write data into them? Make copies on the fly as needed? Sounds complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearingly jupyternotebook built-in time count has bug or something, after ran script version 2 seem vastly faster.